# Exporting data to Excel and applying a format to it

Tags: excel, matlab, formatting, export-to-excel

I want to Export a `1xm-Cellarray` using `xlswrite`. The Cell Array consists of `m` cells each containing a `ixn-Cellarray` where `i` is mostly 2, but can also be 3,4,5 or 6. Here's an example of what the data would look like:

```
a=[{{{'a'},{'b'},{'c'},{'d'};{'a'},{'b'},{'c'},{'d'}}},{{{'a'},{'b'},{'c'},{'d'};{'a'},{'b'},{'c'},{'d'};{'a'},{'b'},{'c'},{'d'}}},{{{'a'},{'b'},{'c'},{'d'};{'a'},{'b'},{'c'},{'d'}}}]

a = 

    {2x4 cell}    {3x4 cell}    {2x4 cell}
```

I want all the cells to be written underneath each other, but I want to be able to see in Excel which rows belonged to one cell. My idea was to put an empty row between on Array cell and another like this

```
exportTable=[];
for jj=1:numel(a)
    exportTable=[exportTable;a{jj};repmat({[]},1,18)];
end
```

and then exporting the `exportTable` using `xlswrite`, but this Looks pretty ugly in the exported sheet and is not easy to read.
Now I'm looking for a way to get the lines of each cell coloured in the same Colour either directly using the Export function in matlab or using Excel with a vector of the corresponding rows as input.
I could achieve the ending Indexes for each cell using

```
rows=cumsum(cellfun(@(x) size(x,1),a))

rows =

     2     5     7
```

But I don't know how to colour rows in Excel based on rownumbers.
The desired Output for my example would look like this:
[image: example output]

Any help using Matlab or Excel is appreciated.

Comment: I would make a simple macro in Excel. I think formatting excel within matlab can get very ugly.

Comment: @ValerioRaco Well, how do you create such a macro in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rows = cumsum(cellfun(@(x) size(x,1),a))

%Create an Excel object.
e = actxserver('Excel.Application');

%Add a workbook.
eWorkbook = e.Workbooks.Add;
e.Visible = 1;

%Make the first sheet active.
eSheets = e.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets;
eSheet1 = eSheets.get('Item',1);
eSheet1.Activate

for i = 1:length(a)
    ai = table2array( cell2table( a{:,i} ) ); % sorry for this construction

    if mod(i,2)
        ai_color = 3;
    else
        ai_color = 4;
    end

    ai_range = ['A',num2str(rows(i)-size(ai,1)+1),':',char('A'-1+size(ai,2)),num2str(rows(i))]; % ... and this :)

    % Set the color of cells
    eSheet1.Range(ai_range).Interior.ColorIndex = ai_color;

    %Put MATLAB data into the worksheet.
    eActivesheetRange = get(e.Activesheet,'Range',ai_range);
    eActivesheetRange.Value = ai;
end


SaveAs(eWorkbook,'myfile.xlsx')

%If the Excel program displays a dialog box about saving the file, select the appropriate response to continue.

%If you saved the file, then close the workbook.
eWorkbook.Saved = 1;
Close(eWorkbook)

%Quit the Excel program and delete the server object.
Quit(e)
delete(e)

%Note:   Make sure that you close workbook objects you create to prevent potential memory leaks.
```

Comment: looks pretty solid. Unfortunatly I can't try it right now, because I don't have a windows system at home. I'll try it during the week and give you feedback/accept your answer. Thank you very much for your efforts though! :)

Comment: solved my problem completly, thank you very much once again!